# Do i need to send eth to a cold wallet that has a balance of 75k in order to transfer to bank account

Tags: transactions, wallets, wallet-transfer, scam

A recovery company claims that they recovered stolen funds from GMT and in process of recovery to clients, I did lose to GMT , but did not engage the company, they called me and advised that I have 73k ready to he transfered, the money was sent to infinity wallet, and in order to be sent, I need to purchase 3 ETH and send it, so the wallet is integrated and they can immediately send the transfer, have anybody been in a situation like this, they assigned a recovery specialist but I have my daughter
Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like an scam.